# Is it possible to use parameter in queryString tag in jrxml file in JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am writing a *JasperReports* program where I want the query to be externalized to properties file.

I am injecting the query as string in my Java program.

In the *jrxml* file I have the following statements:

```xml
<parameter name="mySqlQuery" class="java.lang.String"/>

<queryString> 
    <![CDATA[$P{mySqlQuery}]]>
</queryString>
```

The Java program has the following:

```java
hashmap.put("mySqlQuery", this.mySqlQuery);

JasperReport jasperReportMyClass = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(this.reportMyClass);
JasperPrint jasperPrintMyClass = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReportMyClass, hashmap, con);
jprintList.add(jasperPrintMyClass);
```

Which I am then exporting to excel.

If I am hardcoding the same query directly in the *JRXML* ***queryString*** tags, it works fine.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to use parameter in queryString tag in jrxml file in jasper report?

Yes, it is possible.

Try to use *`$P!{mySqlQuery}`* expression instead of *`$P{mySqlQuery}`* in your jrxml file.

You can read details [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/index.html#query).

Comment: Its $P!{mySqlQuery}.. thanks.. can you please correct the syntax in your answer...